# Any way to move a video from Google+ to YouTube?

Tags: youtube, google-plus

I have a number of videos from my phone on Google+, is there an easy way to get them publicly available on my Youtube channel?  I'm not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There now exists an "Import from Google Photos" button on https://www.youtube.com/upload. It does exactly what you want to do.